# Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange Throw an Exception when nothing selected

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

I tried to handle exception without try/catch to get selected shapes, and the below code throw exception `!=null` didn't work here, any idea

```
PowerPoint.Selection selection = Application.ActiveWindow.Selection;
PowerPoint.ShapeRange shapeRange = selection?.ShapeRange; // Throw Ex 
if (shapeRange != null)
{
    // do some code
}
```

Exception message :

> Selection (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Nothing appropriate is
>   currently selected.

Comment: In VBA, we would first test the ActiveWindow.Selection.Type property. If it equals 0, then nothing is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft is silent for PowerPoint, however for Excel: "The returned object type depends on the current selection (for example, if a cell is selected, this property returns a Range object). The Selection property returns Nothing if nothing is selected."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.selection

I would expect the same for PowerPoint.

I do more Excel with VB rather than PowerPoint with c#, but I guess you could try something in the likes of:

```
if (selection.GetType == null)
```

Hope this give you a track to investigate further